# Customize jQuery countdown Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am looking to customize the CSS and Javascript of the  [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin.I am using this [Gem](https://github.com/mauriciopasquier/jquery-countdown-rails) for the asset pipeline.
Right now I have included in my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.countdown
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tinymce-jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require_tree .
```

`application.css`

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require jquery.countdown
 *= require_self
 */
```

My question here is where to include the `js` and `css` files in my rails app and how to call them in my view once i customize some of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it.

Create a new coffeescript file `app/assets/javascripts/timers.js.coffee`, which contains:

```
Timers =
  init: ->
    @initCountdownUntil()
    @initCountdownSince()

  initCountdownUntil: ->
    $('div[data-countdown-until]').each (index, element) ->
      $element = $(element)
      date = new Date($element.data('countdown-until'))
      $element.countdown(until: date)

  initCountdownSince: ->
    $('div[data-countdown-since]').each (index, element) ->
      $element = $(element)
      date = new Date($element.data('countdown-since'))
      $element.countdown(since: date)

window.Timers = Timers
```

Wherever you initialize your other javascript add:

```
Timers.init()
```

To add a timer to any view, just add a div with a `data-countdown-until` or `data-countdown-since` attribute:

```
<div data-countdown-until="<%= 10.days.from_now %>"></div>
```

When `Timers.init()` is called it looks for any divs that have data-countdown-until or data-countdown-since attributes, parses the time (the time can be in standard ActiveRecord output format, so `@record.created_at` will work fine), and attaches a countdown timer to the div.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to customize some of the CSS by creating a new file with the overrides and making sure it is loaded after the jquery.countdown.css file (for example: jquery.countdown-customization.css), so your application.css would look similar to this:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require 'masonry/transitions'
*= require jquery.countdown
*= require jquery.countdown-customization
*= require_self
*/
```

In the JS you'll initialise all your elements with the class of your choice (for example: 'countdown') with all the options you want. Now the question is: how to get the option values from the view?, one option is to pass it via html data attributes like this:

```
<div class="countdown" data-until="<%= my_object.due_date %>" data-format="dHM"></div>
```

Now back to the JavaScript, the code to initialise your elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.countdown').each(function(){
    $(this).countdown({until: new Date($(this).data('until')), format: $(this).data('format')});
  });
});
```

And that should be it!